# What different between 2 ways of jquery extend?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, extend

I'm coding some jquery plugins, I extended these but I dont know why:

**Method 1**

```
(function($){
    $.fn.myplugin = function() {}
})(jQuery);

$.extend({myplugin : $.fn.myplugin});
```

**Method 2**

```
(function($){
    $.extend({
        myplugin: function() {}
    })
})(jQuery);
```

for #1, I may call $.myplugin().myplugin2().myplugin3();

but with #2, can not use $.myplugin().myplugin2(); it shows myplugin2 is not valid function

---

basically I want to write in #2 because I will not have to declare

```
$.extend({
    myplugin : $.fn.myplugin,
    myplugin2 : $.fn.myplugin2,
    .....});
```

for each plugin. can anyone help me for this?

Comment: IIRC, you are supposed to call `$.myplugin("myplugin2").myplugin3()` with #2

Comment: yes, that's right; or some solution to write #1 but make extend 1 time for all plugins

Comment: Do you need a `$.myPlugin` version? Could you do `$("<div>").myPlugin` instead and only extend `$.fn`?

Answer (score 1):

In both cases you add the function to the global jQuery object, which allos you to call `$.pluginName`.

#1 also adds the plugin to all jQuery element objects, the ones you get when calling the `$` function: `$("#selector")`.

Your plugin probably returns a jQuery element object. So at first you use `$.pluginName` and in the code that follows you call `$.fn.pluginName`. You can't chain calls with #2 because `$.fn.pluginName` is undefined.

This will make more sense when you know that `$.fn` is an alias for `$.prototype`. (The prototype functions are members of all return values of `$()` - using the `new` keyword in the background.)

---

You could create an object with all your plugins to simplify your code:

```
var plugins = {
    myPlugin: function(){},
    myPlugin2: function(){}
}

$.extend($, plugins);
$.extend($.fn, plugins);
```

Comment: thank so much for clarifying, but your code is not best idea I need, if use it, I'll have to type 2 lines for each plugin. I only want to write plugin then it's extended automatically, like #2

Comment: ahhh, I didnt read carefully, perhaps your suggestion is better at this moment, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

`$.fn.myplugin = function() {}` allows you to call your function on a jquery object, like this:

```
$("something").myplugin()
```

Where as

```
$.extend({
    myplugin: function() {}
})
```

makes it so you call your function like this:

```
$.myplugin()
```

In your first example, you are doing both of these.  The 2nd is only doing the 2nd one.